# wordpress post query elseif

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm trying to run a custom query for a WP blog page - to layout certain posts in the query differently, but having trouble executing the elseif statement properly. Here's my code layout:

```
<div class="row">

<?php // WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
  'pagination'             => false,
  'posts_per_page'         => '7',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );?>

<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $post = $posts[0]; $c=0;?>
<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<?php $c++;
if( !$paged && $c == 1) :?>

<div class="post">
            <!-- POST FORMATTING HERE -->
</div><!-- /post -->
<div class="row">
<div class="row">
<?php $c++;
elseif( !$paged && $c == 2) :?>
<div class="post">
        <!-- POST FORMATTING HERE -->
</div><!-- /post -->
<?php $c++;
elseif( !$paged && $c == 3) :?>
<div class="post">
    <!-- POST FORMATTING HERE -->
</div><!-- /post -->
            </div><!-- /row -->
    </div><!-- /row -->
</div><!-- /row -->
<hr />
<div class="row post-tiles">
<?php else :?>

<div class="post">
            <!-- POST FORMATTING HERE -->
</div><!-- /post -->    

<?php endif;?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!-- /post-tiles -->
```

Here's how it's functioning right now:

```
<?php // WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
'pagination'             => false,
'posts_per_page'         => '7',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );?>


<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $post = $posts[0]; $c=0;?>
<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<?php $c++;
if( !$paged && $c == 1) :?>

<!-- This Works -->

<?php $c++;
elseif( !$paged && $c == 2) :?>

<!-- This Works -->

<?php $c++;
elseif( !$paged && $c == 3) :?>

<!-- This DOES NOT Work -->

<?php else :?>

<!-- This Works -->

<?php endif;?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: You need another `<?php endif;?>` after the last endwhile (to close the "if have posts".

Comment: Ah - I do have it. Sorry - it didn't get copied into the code block. Thanks for pointing that out though. I've added it now to the code block in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely incrementing $c too often. If you want it to increment once each loop, delete the two $c++ lines above the elseif statements.